# I don't know what to do with a .apk file

Tags: android

I was given a library on an .apk file.
see:
http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/downloads/list

I assume it contains the package that I will have to import, but what do I do with it?

Comment: What you do for living? Continue that :-) just joking :-)

Comment: It isn't Android programming.  That is for sure.  Actually, we are trying to use the Android as an instrumental base for some experiments we need to run.  It is inexpensive and has the GPS, magnetometers, and accelerometers we need.  Unfortunately, some of the stuff we need to do is not normal for the Android and quite difficult.  It's been a fire hose experience the last two weeks (and I started at zero).  Some of my questions have been dumb, but I have only had one class in Computer Science and am not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually downloading and using this APK, it appears that what you've downloaded is a pre-built demo of the serial port API. If you want to know how to use it, you should examine its sources rather than the sample application.

From the link you provided, you can click the Source tab, then click the Browse link. Inside the 'trunk' you'll find the sources, which for "android-serialport-api" appear to be a native library along with its Java classes (SerialPort, SerialPortFinder) and a sample application.

Comment: Ah!  There it is.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

[How to use my custom library apk file in other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389435/how-to-use-my-custom-library-apk-file-in-other-applications)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Android expert, though I have used android for a while. I've had .apk files myself in the past, and found that you can use a file manager tool, such as 'Root Explorer' from Speed Software (available for free in the market) to locate and execute your .apk file. My (limited) understanding is that .apk files are self-contained.

HTH