# Does a Library Project require a package name in its AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, android-library, library-project

I am having [this weird problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk) where everything seems to work as expected but Eclipse's Console keeps issuing a `Could not find Library.apk!` error.

Since I have exhausted all possible "voodoo" tricks, I am now thinking perhaps the cause for that error message is that by specifying a package name for the Library project, Eclipse expects and APK?

The documentation on Library Projects in developer.android.com is very short and doesn't explain all the issues that I had to go through in order to make the conversion to library project based application work.

Does a Library Project require a package name in its AndroidManifest.xml?

If the answer is yes, why does Eclipse complain about not finding an APK *when there shouldn't be any* APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue you are having is connected to either the project .classpath or the .project file each located on the top level of your project directory. remove the lib from the project build path, erase the things in there connected to your library and add the build path references again.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out (see other thread). So to answer this particular question, **a Library Project definitely requires a package name in its `AndroidManifest.xml`**. Accepting +1.