# Android app with library can't find the library.apk

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the FinchVideo example from the Programming Android book to work.  It uses the FinchWelcome library.  I've set up FinchWelcome as a Library and in the FinchVideo application I have checked the FinchWelcome library in Properties -> Android.  When I try to run FinchVideo in the emulator it complains that it cannot find FinchWelcome.apk (output below).  I'm building for Android 4.0.3.

While Googling for this problem I've found that a lot of people have this problem with Android apps that use libraries.  No one seems to have found a solution that works consistently, though.  None of the Android books I've seen even talk about how to download libraries.

What is the proper way to handle libraries in Android applications?  Is this a bug in the Eclipse ADT?

Thanks.

```
[FinchVideo] Installing FinchVideo.apk...
[FinchVideo] Success!
[FinchWelcome] Could not find FinchWelcome.apk!
[FinchVideo] Starting activity com.oreilly.demo.pa.finchvideo.FinchVideoActivity on device emulator-5554
```

Comment: Have you tried clean + refresh the project?

Comment: Uh, yes.  It was the first thing I tried.

Comment: I faced the same issue. I updated the ADT plugin to 22.0.4.v201307151829--741630 and the issue was resolved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find Library.apk!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also getting this error ( lets better call it confusing/weird message ) every now and then - my Workaround: just ignore it for now and wait for a new ADT version
And yes - imho this is a bug in ADT - Android is really nice, but ADT needs a lot of more attention for sure ..-)

Comment: Converted this comment into the answer below in order to include code.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you have struggled on the same corner yet for me the solution is to add the library in the Android Properties of you project rather than as project in the Java Properties ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the FitchVideo app. installed on the emulator.  When I run it it crashes immediately with

```
D/AndroidRuntime(505): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(505): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Nothing in the rest of the stack trace refers to the Fitch source (app. or lib.).

I can't tell if that is a problem with the way that ADT installed the app. and lib on the emulator or if it is some other problem.

I don't think I'm going to spend much more time with the code from the Programming Android book.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

In your FinchVideo project you will need to add the reference to FinchWelcome as a jar-file library reference rather that a project library reference.

Hope this helps.