# "Could not find mopub-android-sdk.apk!"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mopub

I am attempting to incorporate mopub adverts into my game and get the error "Could not find mopub-android-sdk.apk!" reported in eclipse's console window when attempting to run the game. I am puzzled as to why it should be looking for an apk file at all - surely an apk file is a wrapped up program to execute (correct me if I'm wrong) - but I think mopub is supposed to be a library. Surely all the mopub functionality should be built into my single game apk, shouldn't it?

**EDIT:** The console output looks like this...

```
 ------------------------------
 Android Launch!
 adb is running normally.
 Performing com.company.game.Splash activity launch
 Automatic Target Mode: using device '0123456789ABCDEF'
 Uploading Game.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
 Installing Game.apk...
 Success!
 Could not find mopub-android-sdk.apk!
 Starting activity com.company.game.Splash on device 0123456789ABCDEF
```

So it looks to me like its already installed my game.apk - why on earth would it then want to install mopub-android-sdk.apk?

**EDIT:** I just tried getting MoPub's sample demo working and that was fine. So now I'm suspecting its something I have set up incorrectly in my game project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have an unnecessary reference to the MoPub project in the *Java Build Path* section of your project's *Properties*. See the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6346303/1212966).

Answer (score 1):

You should do just clean the project & build it again..