# Eclipse referring to .class file instead of workspace java file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have 10 maven java projects and a war projects.

During debugging, my eclipse is taking me to .class file even same java class file is present in the workspace.

Any pointers how to fix it

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540184/class-file-opens-instead-of-java-while-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

- In the project's properties, in the Maven group, let the checkbox "Resolve dependencies from Workspace" be **checked**.
- Ensure that the projects currently opened in the workspace have **the same groupId, artifactId and version** that the dependencies referenced in the debugged project's pom. If you have to change some version, execute Maven > Update Maven Project in the project's context menu.

Most probably, the openend projects do not have the same versions that the debugged project's dependencies.