# Working in Eclipse, Java bytecode not updating

Tags: eclipse, bytecode

I am working on a project in Eclipse. Sometimes I am finding when I add a method to a class, the other classes will not acknowledge the method being there. When I open up the declaration of the class I modified, it takes me to the bytecode version of the class, not the source code class I'm working on. The bytecode class failed to have the new method added to it too.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding, closing and re-opening the project. But this problem still persists. What can I do?

Comment: This does occur with only one project? Do you have more than one source folder or something like that?

Comment: I do not. It's a single project with multiple packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. This made pressing F3 on a class declaration go back to the .java file and not the .class file

[Using Android library in eclipse and jumping to class files instead of source file that is within eclipse workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682074/using-android-library-in-eclipse-and-jumping-to-class-files-instead-of-source-fi)