# Could not find gridlayout_v7.apk

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to make my app switch between two activities with buttons. The first activity comes up and I can click on the button, but then a notification pops up that says "Unfortunately, *projectname* has stopped."

This is the error that comes up on the console:

```
[2012-10-18 09:54:46 - gridlayout_v7] Could not find gridlayout_v7.apk!
```

This is what the rest of the console posts:

```
[2012-10-18 09:54:38 - PersonalLibrary] Android Launch!
[2012-10-18 09:54:38 - PersonalLibrary] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-18 09:54:38 - PersonalLibrary] Performing com.balaka.personallibrary.LibraryMenu activity launch
[2012-10-18 09:54:38 - PersonalLibrary] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'test' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-18 09:54:38 - PersonalLibrary] Uploading PersonalLibrary.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-18 09:54:39 - PersonalLibrary] Installing PersonalLibrary.apk...
[2012-10-18 09:54:46 - PersonalLibrary] Success!
[2012-10-18 09:54:46 - gridlayout_v7] Could not find gridlayout_v7.apk!
[2012-10-18 09:54:46 - PersonalLibrary] Starting activity com.balaka.personallibrary.LibraryMenu on device emulator-5554
[2012-10-18 09:54:48 - PersonalLibrary] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.balaka.personallibrary/.LibraryMenu }
```

I've tried to find answers others places online but there is no mention of the file.

Comment: have u added your new activity in AndroidMenifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes, like this: '<activity
            android:label="@string/library"
            android:name=".Library" >  
  </activity>  '

Comment: Does your app use any third-party library?

Comment: No, all I'm doing right now is trying to get one button to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk), you need to remove the project dependency to gridlayout_v7 and add the dependency to gridlayout_v7 as an "Android" dependency in project properties. That solved the problem for  me.