# android-beacon-library can not detect iBeacon advertiser

Tags: ibeacon, android-ibeacon

Due to the problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630735/fail-to-configure-the-android-beacon-library-in-eclipse), I configure the [mornitoring example code](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) as follows, however my app can not detect the iBeacon advertiser deployed.

1. new a mornitoring Activity named MainActivity, except the onCreate method, all other code are the same as the sample code.

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
    protected static final String TAG = "MornitoringActivity";
    public static final String UUID = "UUID: D57092AC-DFAA-446C-8EF3-C81AA22815B5";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    TextView mInfoView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mInfoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_info_lable);
    beaconManager.setDebug(true);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "on create complete!"); 
}
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "on destroy complete!"); 
}
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!"); 
        mInfoView.setText("I just saw an beacon for the first time!"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
        mInfoView.setText("I no longer see an beacon");
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state); 
        mInfoView.setText("I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", Identifier.parse(UUID), null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
}
```

}

2. copy class.jar in    android-beacon-library/libs/ into myProject/libs/, and add it to build path
3. manually edit the AndroidManifest.xml, here is my xml file,

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.mymornitoring"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="18"
       android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity> 
   <service
       android:enabled="true" 
       android:exported="true" 
       android:isolatedProcess="false" 
       android:label="beacon" 
       android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService">
   </service>
   <service 
       android:enabled="true" 
       android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor">
   </service>

   <receiver android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.StartupBroadcastReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   </application>
   ```
4. Use Macbook running the BeaconOSX app to perform as an iBeacon advertiser.(And I've use the AirLocate app on iPhone 4s to confirm the iBeacon advertiser works, however fail to be detected by the iBeacon Locate android app developed by Radius Networks)
5. Then I ran myProject on Nexus 5, the logcat messages are as below

```html
11-06 10:49:08.838: I/BeaconService(5023): beaconService version 2.0 is starting up
11-06 10:49:08.878: D/BeaconService(5023): No org.altbeacon.beacon.SimulatedScanData class exists.
11-06 10:49:08.878: I/BeaconService(5023): binding
11-06 10:49:08.908: I/BeaconService(5023): start monitoring received
11-06 10:49:08.908: D/BeaconService(5023): startMonitoring called
11-06 10:49:08.908: D/BeaconService(5023): Currently monitoring 1 regions.
11-06 10:49:08.928: D/BeaconService(5023): Waiting to stop scan for another 1100 milliseconds
11-06 10:49:08.928: D/BeaconService(5023): Scan started
11-06 10:49:09.938: D/BeaconService(5023): Waiting to stop scan for another 99 milliseconds
11-06 10:49:10.038: D/BeaconService(5023): Done with scan cycle
11-06 10:49:10.048: D/BeaconService(5023): Restarting scan.  Unique beacons seen last cycle: 0 Total beacon advertisement packets seen: 0
```

This idicate the BeaconService works well.

```
11-06 10:48:41.238: D/BtGatt.GattService(1483): registerClient() - UUID=6eaaf541-90fb-4e88-a0d5-1f267769128b
11-06 10:48:41.248: D/BtGatt.GattService(1483): onClientRegistered() - UUID=6eaaf541-90fb-4e88-a0d5-1f267769128b, clientIf=5
11-06 10:48:41.248: D/BtGatt.GattService(1483): startScan() - queue=0
11-06 10:48:41.248: D/BtGatt.GattService(1483): startScan() - adding client=5
11-06 10:48:51.258: D/BtGatt.GattService(1483): stopScan() - queue=1
11-06 10:48:51.258: D/BtGatt.GattService(1483): stopScan() - queue empty; stopping scan
11-06 10:48:51.258: D/BtGatt.GattService(1483): unregisterClient() - clientIf=5


11-06 10:48:41.238: D/BluetoothAdapter(1365): startLeScan(): null
11-06 10:48:41.248: D/BluetoothAdapter(1365): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5    
11-06 10:48:51.258: D/BluetoothAdapter(1365): stopLeScan()    
11-06 10:49:08.918: D/BluetoothAdapter(5023): startLeScan(): null    
11-06 10:49:08.928: D/BluetoothAdapter(5023): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5    
11-06 10:49:10.038: D/BluetoothAdapter(5023): stopLeScan()    
11-06 10:49:10.048: D/BluetoothAdapter(5023): startLeScan(): null
```

I notice that there are two apps on my Nexus 5, who print the same BluetoothAdapter log msgs. Does this matter? And the didEnterRegion/didExitRegion has never been called. What could the problem be?

Comment: Please show more of your `MainActivity` including the code that implements `onBeaconServiceConnect` and your code that defines your Region used in the call to `startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion`.

Comment: Also, if you want to use the Android Locate app to detect proprietary beacons you must paste the beacon layout expression for that proprietary beacon under Settings -> Custom Beacon Parser.

Comment: hi,@davidgyoung. I've re-edit my post to show the whole code of my MainActivity. I need your help sooooo much, thx in advance!

Comment: David, have you got any demo projects developed in Eclipse using android-beacon-library.If so, can I just download the project somewhere to see the difference between your demo and mine? I suppose this might be a nice way to learn to config the library

Comment: It looks like your UUID is in the wrong format.  Try changing: `public static final String UUID = "UUID: D57092AC-DFAA-446C-8EF3-C81AA22815B5";` to `public static final String UUID = "D57092AC-DFAA-446C-8EF3-C81AA22815B5";`

Comment: Yes, there is an Eclipse reference app here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference but it does require configuring the Android Beacon Library as a dependent Android library in Eclipse.