# ClassNotFoundException when starting any new activity

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

When I try to start any activity beside MainActivity in application, I experience a crash in some devices.
as I can see in crashAnalytics it does not depend on the version or brand of the device or android version,

fatal exception don't refers to any line in my project.

already tried to delete .gradle folder / clear project, does not work.

```
03-30 19:13:46.458 7597-7597/ru.sberleasing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.sberleasing, PID: 7597
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda
        at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
        at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:476)
        at java.lang.reflect.AbstractMethod.getParameterTypes(AbstractMethod.java:166)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:170)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:673)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:566)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:279)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1055)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:268)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1554)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1442)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1395)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:167)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1148)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:51)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1416)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1322)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3417)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.sberleasing-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.sberleasing-2/lib/x86, /data/app/ru.sberleasing-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:53)
        at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:476) 
        at java.lang.reflect.AbstractMethod.getParameterTypes(AbstractMethod.java:166) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:170) 
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:673) 
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:566) 
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:279) 
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087) 
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1055) 
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:268) 
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087) 
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1554) 
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) 
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1442) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1395) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:167) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1148) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:51) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1416) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1322) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690) 
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3152) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3417) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 39 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: check if missing class is part of the SDK [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/classes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failing to launch activity due to ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702179/failing-to-launch-activity-due-to-classnotfoundexception)

Answer (score 0):

in my case problem was in Compile version.
probably voximplant-sdk conflicts with api 29, version downgrading solved the problem for now.