# To check or not to check "IsLibrary"?

Tags: android, apk, adt, android-library, library-project

I built my app using a library project (that I also created, to be reused in other apps). It builds fine, but when I try to install & run it through Eclipse (Ctrl+F11), I get this red **Could not find MyLib.apk!** error line in my console:

Console output:

```
[2013-11-30 14:42:59 - MyApp] ------------------------------
[2013-11-30 14:42:59 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2013-11-30 14:42:59 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-30 14:42:59 - MyApp] Performing com.sfinja.myapp.ActivitySubClass activity launch
[2013-11-30 14:42:59 - MyApp] Automatic Target Mode: using device '5752068FC64500EA'
[2013-11-30 14:43:00 - MyApp] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-11-30 14:43:00 - MyLib] Could not find MyLib.apk!
[2013-11-30 14:43:00 - MyApp] Starting activity com.sfinja.myapp.ActivitySubClass on device 5752068FC64500EA
[2013-11-30 14:43:00 - MyApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.sfinja.myapp/.ActivitySubClass }
```

So I searched SO and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6450971/2946787) which solves the problem by simply unchecking the library project's `Is Library`checkbox.

Sure enough, my Library Project (MyLib) had this checkbox checked so I unchecked it and I no longer receive this error in the console, but then I started getting runtime NullPointerExceptions.

This clearly suggests that I have a problem in my project setup/configuration (although it builds fine) but in order to find what it is, I believe I need to understand a bit more about this confusing checkbox:

1. I have other library projects used in this app, all having the `Is Library` checkbox **checked** but none of them presents the problem exhibited by MyLib. So, to check or not to check "IsLibrary"?
2. If it is a library, why should the `Is Library` checkbox be unchecked? Is that thread's correct answer from 2 years ago still valid?
3. Is the **Could not find APK!** essentially a "red herring" for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recall encountering a problem similar to yours that drove me nuts. I also thought that unchecking the projects **Is Library** checkbox would solve the problem but in actuality it didn't.

After lots of lost hours I then found the culprit: An extra, redundant, wicked and totally misleading and destructive line in the project's `.classpath`:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/RogueProjLib"/>
```

(I had no idea how it snuck in)

Once I removed it, the the *"Could not find RogueProjLib.apk!"* went away and project installed and ran fine, with the **Is Library** checkbox checked!

Based on that, I would answer your questions as follows:

1. Your other library projects aren't probably in that `.classpath`... Yes, do check **Is Library**.
2. Question irrelevant because it *should* be checked. The answer from 2 years ago is no longer relevant with the latest Eclipse/ADT bundle.
3. Yes, it is a red herring: Instead of telling you "there is a weird line in my .classpath with which I don't know what to do", it just emits that cryptic "Could not find APK" message.

Hope this helps.