# Including an APK in another project

Tags: android, apk

How can I add an APK as dependency in my project in Android Studio?

Comment: convert your project into library and use it as dependency

Comment: why would you need it? how are you going to use that APK?

Comment: I need to use some methods from this apk project (I do not have source code), so I need to add it as dependency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use my custom library apk file in other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389435/how-to-use-my-custom-library-apk-file-in-other-applications)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. Acceptable types are `.jar` and `.aar` and internal library project module.

Best you can do is to change the app-module to library module and then include it as depenancy.

**You can achieve it as follows:**

1. Open the module-level `build.gradle` file.
2. Delete the line for the `applicationId`. Only an Android app module can define this.
3. At the top of the file, you should see the following:

   `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

   **Change it to the following:**

   `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
4. Save the file and click File > Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: Thanks  for your reply. I do not have source code for this apk in order to build it in a different way. Is there a way to get the source code?

Comment: @cthem Unfortunately you can't do that. If its internal you can request for source code from the team. But since its external, you can't